# mongodb : search an array of hashes

Tags: arrays, search, mongodb, nested

> db.test.insert({_id:1,communications:[{type:'sms'}]})
>
> db.test.find()
> { "_id" : 1, "communications" : [ { "type" : "sms" } ] }

Ok, its inserted

> db.test.find({'communications':{type:'sms'}})
> { "_id" : 1, "communications" : [ { "type" : "sms" } ] }

Ok, I can find it if its an exact match

> db.test.update({_id:1}, {communications:[{type:'sms',call_id:9878}]}

Now I updated it such that the hash nested in the array has two keys

> .test.update({_id:1}, {communications:[{type:'sms',call_id:9878}]})

But I can't find it bc the hash is not the exact match! NOOOOO!

> db.test.find({'communications':{type:'sms'}}).count()
> =>0

So, how can I do a search like that where I want to match on one of the keys in a hash in an array?

Comment: See AdaTheDev's response for correct answer (dot notation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood correctly (no guarantees I have!), then I think what you are looking for is the dot notation.

```
db.test.find({'communications.type':'sms'}).count()
```

Here's the [reference on MongoDb.org](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation+%28Reaching+into+Objects%29) with all the examples.

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed that. THanks AdaTheDev.

Comment: Also have a look at the $elemMatch operator which is the more appropriate approach for element filtering in most cases.